# How to sum the total amount in PowerApps

Tags: powerapps

How to sum the total amount of lines (customerEmail)?

```
 AddColumns(
  Table({
    orderDate: "Lenovo Thinkpad",
    orderId: "Procurement",
    ordererValue: 10,
    customer: "499.99"
  },
  {
    orderDate: "Mazda RX8",
    orderId: "Procurement",
    ordererValue: 2,
    customer: "2199.80"
  }),
  "customerEmail", ordererValue * customer)
```

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tF3B0.png)